# How many strings of length 17 contain at least 5 ones?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This is for binary strings, as in 1's and 0's.

**My friend said:**

$\sum\limits_{k=5}^{17} {17 \choose k}  = 127858$

**While my answer was much longer to show but I believe is correct:**

Basically for exactly 5 ones if you start with or end with a 1 then you have 2($2^{11}$) then add to that the possibility of the ones not being in the middle an so get 11($2^{10}$). Then sum up thus for exactly 5 ones you will get 15360.

Using the same logic you get 7168 for exactly 6 ones.

Repeat this logic for exactly 7 to 17 ones, until you arrive at:

15360+7168+3328+1536+704+320+144+64+28+12+5+2+1 = 28672.

**So:**

His answer is 127858 while mine is 28672. Who is correct? Or did we both mess up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these binary strings, e.g. $11001100011101001$?

Comment: Yes they are (1's and 0's). Should have been clearer, sorry.

Comment: Your friend is correct. For exactly five 1s, the number of strings is $\binom{17}{5} = 6188$ (as there are those many ways of choosing the positions for the 1s, and then the rest of the string gets fixed as 0s). How did you get your 15360 number? It's way too high. (If your string starts with five 1s, and it has exactly five 1s, it means that the remaining 12 digits are necessarily 0, so there is exactly one string containing exactly five 1s and all of them in the initial place! Your $2^{11}$ number, however you arrived at it, is surely overcounting something.

Comment: From the wording quoted, which makes no mention of consecutive, your friend is right. But she worked a little too too hard, the number is $2^{17}-\sum_0^4 \binom{17}{k}$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the 5th one is at place $k+1$. Then one must place 4 ones in a sequence of length $k$, which counts for ${k\choose 4}$ possibilities, and the $16-k$ remaining places are free, which counts for $2^{16-k}$ possibilities. Thus the number is
$$
\sum_{k=4}^{17}{k\choose4}2^{16-k},
$$
that is, 127858. Sorry, you lost. :-)

Comment: Your answer of $127658$ does not match either the OP's or his friend's.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Mistyped, thanks.

Comment: Noooooooooo :(. Thanks for the reply, yeah my way is hard to explain guess that's why it's incorrect!

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is correct.  The first term in the sum is the number of ways to choose $5$ positions for $1$'s, leaving the other $12$ for zeros.  Each term covers a different number of $1$'s, so they are disjoint possibilities.  Adding them together is correct.

I don't understand your logic.  In your sum, the last $1$ is presumably the number of ways to have $17$ $1$'s, which is correct.  There are $17$ ways to have $16$ $1$'s, not $2$.

Comment: Guess if I can't explain my answer then I don't understand it enough myself. That explains why I'm wrong. Thanks for the reply :), now I know.